# Как заблокировать мышь и клавиатуру?

Tags: c++builder, windows

Как в С++ заблокировать клаву и мышь или только мышь. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

```
    void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  HINSTANCE hDll;
  //ниже прототип будущей функции
  DWORD __stdcall (*BlockInput)(bool Status);
  DWORD Result;
  Memo1->Lines->Add("");
  Memo1->Lines->Add("Загрузка функции BlockInput()...");
  hDll = LoadLibrary("User32.dll");
  Memo1->Lines->Add("hDll = " + IntToHex(int(hDll), 8));
  BlockInput = (DWORD __stdcall (*)(bool Status))GetProcAddress(hDll,
  "BlockInput");
  Memo1->Lines->Add("BlockInput = " + IntToHex(int(BlockInput), 8));
  if(!BlockInput) {
    Memo1->Lines->Add("Ошибка!!!");
    FreeLibrary(hDll);
    return;
  }
  Memo1->Lines->Add("Выполняем BlockInput(true)...");
  Result = BlockInput(true);
  Memo1->Lines->Add("Result = " + IntToStr(Result));
  if(Result) {
    Memo1->Lines->Add("Теперь клиатура и мышь доступны только, если нажать CTRL+ALT+DEL");
    Memo1->Lines->Add("Ждем 15 сек...");
    Sleep(15000);
  }
  else
    Memo1->Lines->Add("Ошибка!!!");
  Memo1->Lines->Add("Восстанавливаем все как было...");
  BlockInput(false);
  FreeLibrary(hDll);
  Memo1->Lines->Add("Готово.");
}
```

Гуглится за минуту
вот [линк](http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-builder/thread343516.html) откуда скопировал